# How do I ensure a SAML Assertion's Identity Provider with an embedded X509 Certificate is Legitimate?

Tags: validation, saml, trust

I am trying to implement a SAML Service Provider in order to allow for SSO to a cloud-based application, this application can host multiple tenants or companies.  Normally, the user enters an e-mail address (which acts as their User ID) and their password to log in (the tenant would be identified by a URL parameter).

The SAML assertion that is received has the X509 certificate embedded in the payload, which is used to validate the signature of the SAML.  While the signature can be used to verify that the assertion is valid, there is concern that someone other than the Identity Provider can generate their own public/private keys, sign their own assertion with a correctly "guessed" valid tenant ID and user e-mail address, then potentially gain access to the application.

What is a mechanism or technique used to identify that an assertion and its embedded certificate came from a specific identity provider other than the information contained inside the SAML payload?  While I have read that certificates could be downloaded from identity providers, there is concern that those certificates would expire or become revoked, and additionally, we would also have to store them on our side.  There is a legitimate concern that these scenarios would cause downtime for users.

One other small question, as we require a tenant ID to determine which tenant is signing on a particular user account, is it common (or proper) to provide that identifier through the URI, such as in the URL path or as a parameter on our endpoint receiving the SAML assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SAML Trust**

When you implement your SAML SP, you will be asked to *pre-configure* the signing certificate of your target SAML IdP. Therefore, your SP will only trust any incoming assertions signed with that particular signing certificate.

**SAML Configuration**

Configuration of a SAML SP can be done by setting up all IdP parameters including signing certificate manually, or by specifying a metadata file which contains all IdP parameters, including the signing certificate.

You may download the metadata file from IdP and use it locally in your SAML SP, or specify the URL of the metadata file and let your SAML SP to download and use it.

You may refer to Azure AD's SAML metadata URL as an example:
https://nexus.microsoftonline-p.com/federationmetadata/saml20/federationmetadata.xml

Obviously, this URL should be TLS/SSL protected and its content should only be modified by the IdP.

**SAML Signing Certificate Rotation**

When a signing certificate is rotated, the trust between IdP and SP is lost. You will need to re-configure your SP to trust the new certificate directly or refreshing the metadata file.

If you choose to configure your SAML SP by specifying an IdP metadata URL, you may consider configuring your SAML SP library to download and refresh the metadata regularly from IdP.

In this way, your SAML SP will have a trusted way to validate the latest signing certificate even though the certificate might be changed.

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  I needed to identify what extra information I need to store (in this case, the IdP URL to retrieve the certificate metadata) and what may need to be done when the IdP certificate is revoked or expired.  Thank you!